# NodeJS request module - body on http.IncomingMessage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

I'm looking into the node's [request](https://github.com/request/request) module, and documentation says that callback accepts three params - `error`, `response` (`http.IncomingMessage`) and `body`.

When making a request, I found that body also available as a property on the `response` object.
Is that reliable? Can I just omit last param in the callback and use `response.body` instead?

Comment: yes it does, why not just try it and see what happens?

Comment: I'm just curious why documentation doesn't provide this information. Can they guarantee that I receive a body for every types of requests? Or if it just an coincidence?

Comment: fair enough, its really just a convenience method, so we dont have to do response.body, request will return a body for every request that has a body to return...the body could just be an error too, a response is simply an object that is returned from an api, request just makes doing that easy

Answer (score 3):

`response.body` is not always the same as the `body` argument.  If any processing is requested on the response such as decompression, then the `body` argument will be the result of that processing, but `response.body` may not reflect that processing.  You should use the `response` argument.  Here's one example from the documentation:

> For backwards-compatibility, response compression is not supported by
>   default. To accept gzip-compressed responses, set the gzip option to
>   true. Note that the body data passed through request is automatically
>   decompressed while the response object is unmodified and will contain
>   compressed data if the server sent a compressed response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `body` is just a convenience for `response.body` so they are guaranteed to always be the same.

You can verify this by checking [the source code](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L1154).

```
self.emit('complete', response, response.body)
```

and elsewhere in the same file the `complete` event is handled

```
self.on('error', self.callback.bind())
self.on('complete', self.callback.bind(self, null))
```

This is only true of the `response` passed to the callback. The `response` object passed to the response *event* is a standard `http.IncomingMessage` and as such has no `body` property.